# Space of biholomorphic maps into a Riemann surface

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, teichmuller-theory

Let $F$ be a Riemann surface and $Q\in F$. Consider $U:=(\mathbb{C}\cup\infty)\setminus [-1,1]^2$. I am interested in the space
$$X:=\{f:U\to F;\,\text{$f:U\to f(U)$ biholomorphic and $f(\infty)=Q$}\},$$
endowed with the compact–open topology. I would expect $X$ to be contractible because $U$ is contractible, but I simply know too little about these kind of spaces.

Comment: Is there a reason you take this $U$ as your domain? It would seem more natural to work with the unit disk, say.

Comment: +1 to Christian Remling. You will then have $\{f: D\to F, f(0)=Q\}$

Comment: If $F={\mathbb C}$ then your space is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. Most likely, this is always the case.

Comment: In the case when =ℂ (assuming the normalization at =0 and ∈ unit disk) one uses the isotopy given by (,)=()/, ∈(0,1]. As →0, this converges to the linear function ↦′(0). Thus,  deformation retracts to ${\mathbb C}^\times$ (so it is not contractible). The same argument works when $F$ is the unit disk. Some version of this argument might also work for general surfaces.

Comment: Oh okay … so if I additionally fix a tangent vector $0\ne v\in T_QF$ and demand that $f'(0)=v$, then $X$ would be contractible?

Comment: @ChristianRemling: You’re right, and for my problem, it is actually sufficient to consider the unit disk.